# How to get element type in C++?

Tags: c++, string, indexing, char

I am a beginner at programming in C++, I would like to ask you, what is the algorithm/ way to see what kind of element is the following in a char / string.

For example, if I have

```
char b[]="Ab 3";
```

and the index, let's say "i" is

```
i=2;
```

this means that on i=3 there is '3'.
My question: Does there exist an algorithm, which tells me, if I am on index 2, what type of element is on index 3? In our case an 'int'.

Thank you very much!

Comment: [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) might be sufficient.

Comment: Note that character `'3'` and integer `3` are not the same value. To convert a `char` digit to its `int` value, do this: `int n = c - '0';`. (Of course, this only works if `isdigit(c)` is true.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type for any element in a char array will always be char. You can, however, check if the char is a digit with [isdigit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/)(ch).

Comment: And to finish it off, there are `isalpha` etc functions as well, so one can check against each of those to find out what the character is. Of course this starts failing spectacularly if using Unicode.

Answer (score 4):

You can use standard C functions (or corresponding  C++ functions) from header `<cctype>`. They are

```
isalnum
isalpha
isblank
iscntrl
isdigit
ishraph
islower
isprint
ispunct
isspace
isupper
isxdigit
```

For your example std::isdigit( b[2] ), std::isxdigit( b[2] ), std::isgraph( b[2] ) and also std::isprint( b[2] ) will return a non-zero value

Take into account that the type of any element of a character array is char. Using these functions you can check for example whether a character is a digit or an alpha and so on.